# Get element list with a specific id

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

For example, i have two tables ('intervalosHorarios' and 'entregas' [1_n]) and i want to show 'entregas' list from specific 'intervalosHorarios' id. I tried the following but it didn't work.

**Tables**[image]

**Controller List**

```
 public function entregas_lista($idCarga) {

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $datos = array(
            'title' => "entregas", // En la vista 'header' tendré una variable $title
            'username' => "Administrador"
        );

        $this->load->view('commons/header', $datos);

        //Quitamos los botones de añadir y quitar
        $crud->unset_add();
        $crud->unset_edit();

        $crud->set_language("spanish");
        $crud->set_theme('bootstrap');
        $crud->set_table('entregas');



        $crud->where('idCarga =', $idCarga);



        $crud->display_as('idCarga', 'Nº Entrega');
        $crud->set_subject('Carga / Descarga'); 
        $crud->set_relation('idCarga', 'intervalosHorarios', 'intervaloHorario');

        $crud->columns('fechaCita', 'horaCita', 'numeroEntrega', 'cliente', 'Origen', 'Destino', 'cargaPrevista', 'entregaPrevista', 'accion', 'estado');




        $output = $crud->render();




        $this->_example_output($output);


        //---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/footer.php'  ------------- /
        $this->load->view('commons/footer');
    }




    function _example_output($output = null) {
        $this->load->view('example', (array) $output);
    }
```

Comment: post table image

Comment: table posted @Parvez

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I only have modified this line from:

```
$crud->set_relation('idCarga', 'intervalosHorarios', 'intervaloHorario');
```

to:

```
$crud->set_relation('idIntervaloHorario', 'intervalosHorarios', 'intervaloHorario');
```

Then I have erased the database and it worked perfectly.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well... looks like there is a persistent problem, it only shows the first element added and not the other...

Answer (score 0):

If that's all the code that you wrote inside your method, the problem is that you are not querying the database.

Please see the official documentation [here](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/where) .

You need to write your method like this :

public function entregas_lista($idCarga) {

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();       
$crud->set_table('entregas');
$crud->where('idCarga =', $idCarga);

$result = $crud->render();

return $result;
```

}

Comment: I have posted full method and the implementations works, but i'm unable to filter by id

Comment: In : function _example_output($output = null) put this :         $this->load->view('example', [ 'data' => $output]); . Then go to the view an write at the begining : var_dump($data);exit; . And see if you have any data.

Comment: hum.. I think i'm not explaining well. I'm using grocery crud library and better don't touch it code. But the problem is, when I clic on 'intervaloHorario' it show me all 'entregas' items and i want to show only the 'entregas' items that are included into that 'intervaloHorario' -
 @Florin Popescu